# Showing Date in a specific format

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I need to make the date format that I entered into the database look exactly the same as when i view it. Eg. Currently my format is 2013-12-21, but when i view it, it shows 12/21/2013. It's quite confusing because when I edit the date in my form, it's in the 12/21/2013 format and the database wont accept it when i change the date to something like 12/23/2013. Please help. Thanks

(btw, it just auto formatted my date. I didn't even use the `<%formatdatetime%>` function.)

EDIT: Sorry for the lack of information guys. This is what's happening. 
1. I created a form to add date amongst othes to mysql. Eg. Purchase date, item, etc (sql wants it in yyyy-mm-dd format and that's how i enter it.
2. created a view list to select which rows i want to update. (Used

```
<%=Formatdatetime(f_purchasedate,2)%>
```

to show date only without time as it was 12/21/2013 12:00:00 AM)
3. created an update form.

Now the problem is it shows the date as 12/21/2013 instead of 2013-12-21. So when i submit the form after altering other fields, it says date error. I have to manually type the format 2013-12-21 for all my dates before i can submit the form.

i'm guessing it has something to do with this line of mine.

```
purchasedate.Text = ODBCdataset.Tables("tbl_vm").Rows(0).Item(2)
```

tried this but it doesnt help either...

```
formatDateTime('purchasedate').Text.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") = ODBCdataset.Tables("tbl_vm").Rows(0).Item(2)
```

Comment: didn't understand your question too vague. have a look at [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: > but when i view it, it shows 12/21/2013 <-- how are you viewing? the actual storage of mysql datetime type is described in [Date and Time Data Type Representation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/date-and-time-data-type-representation.html)

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details. Please tell me if the details are not sufficient. Thanks

Comment: formatDateTime('purchasedate') in this 'purchasedate' is the column name or the textbox id??

Comment: the textbox id is purchasedate, the column name is f_purchasename. Thanks

Comment: I think it is better for you to edit the query used to retrieve the date from MySQL in the format you require to show in textbox. check this [MySQL DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Comment: I dont think that's possible because i'm actually selecting by id. SELECT * FROM tbl_vehiclemanagement WHERE f_id = " & Request.QueryString("id")  Used to work when I was using recordset. Even though the date format was wrong I still managed to insert it into sql with this. <input name="date" type="text" value="<% = FormatDateTime(RS.Fields("f_Date").Value.ToString(),2)%>">

Comment: I would never recommend `SELECT * ...` code becomes difficult to manage. `FormatDateTime` can only return value depends on your system Date Time format. if you want specific format you can try this `DitectCast(RS.Fields("f_Date").Value, DateTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DATE_FORMAT(date,format)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
Select DATE_FORMAT('Your Date Value'),%Y-%m-%d) as Date from table_name
```

Or

You can pass the value to a variable like below

```
 purchasedate.Text = CType(ODBCdataset.Tables("tbl_vehiclemanagement").Rows(0).Item(2).ToString, DateTime).ToString("yyyy/mm/dd")
```

Comment: I'm using this <%purchasedate.Text = ODBCdataset.Tables("tbl_vehiclemanagement").Rows(0).Item(2)%> to fill my textfield. How to I get it to change to the solution you recommended? Thanks

Comment: i have changed as per your requirements check it

Comment: I've tried it but it says "Input string was not in a correct format. " Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: .item(2).tostring("yyyy/mm/dd) instead use it with column name like this .("columname").tostring("yyyy/mm/dd)

Comment: Do you mean like this? <%purchasedate.Text = ODBCdataset.Tables("tbl_vehiclemanagement").Rows(0).("f_purchasedate").ToString("yyyy/mm/dd")%> it says BC30203: Identifier expected. I'm still new to this. sorry if i'm asking stupid questions

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!! can I get a brief explanation?

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim date As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/mm/dd")
```

Comment: I actually need to display the date from mysql and not today's date.. Sorry for the mix up..

Comment: So You can simply Replace Your Mysql reader of receved data string with DateTime.Now in code

Comment: How do i do that? my current code is purchasedate.Text = ODBCdataset.Tables("tbl_vehiclemanagement").Rows(0).Item(2) Thanks

Comment: Dim date = ODBCdataset.Tables("tbl_vehiclemanagement").Rows(0).Item(2).ToString("yyyy/mm/dd")